# predictor/corrector and gear integration for positive and negative time steps

Tags: numerical-algorithms, numerical-analysis

I have a predictor method that takes differential equations for 214 biological species and integrates them in time using positive time steps. Right now it is able to successfully integrate the differential equations when the time step is positive, so  it can integrate forwards in time and I was looking to see if it could be integrated backwards in time.  By that I mean I was looking to see if the differential equations could be integrated using a negative time step, based on using the following method for integrating the differential equations.

The predictor method uses the forward Euler equations for each species in order to predict its value at the next time step.

The corrector method uses the trapezoidal rule.  So the predictor-corrector method is based on Heun's method.  It also uses three terms in the gear integration method which is implemented alongside Heun's method.

So I was wondering, is it possible to use this integration with a negative time step, thereby integrating the differential equations backwards in time?

Essentially, I am integrating the differential equations with boundary conditions at time $t = 0$ and using a time step $\Delta$t such that $\Delta$t $> 0$.  So I was looking to see if the integration method I used above could work if I used the same boundary conditions at time $t = 0$ and used a time step such that $\Delta$t $< 0$.  This step size is also denoted as $h$ in various explanations of predictor corrector methods as shown here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictor%E2%80%93corrector_method

If it can be done, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Can you ask your question in a way that doesn't require us to understand a hundred lines of your terse code? We're happy to answer questions about principles but most things involving specific code are off-topic, here.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "integrate in reverse"?  Also I don't know what it means to "take derivatives of a species" or "integrate in time".  Perhaps you can use mathematics to help state your problem more precisely?  I am guessing you are just solving a differential equation, with a boundary condition at $t=0$ (the "left boundary"); and now you want to solve the differential equation, with a boundary condition at $t=t_\text{max}$ (the "right boundary"), or something like that.  Is that right?   Can you edit to clarify?

Comment: It looks like you've created two separate accounts.  If you use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page, you can get the site admins to merge them for you. That means you'll be able to edit your own post without having to get the edits reviewed, and also comment on your own question.